# Where is CountedSet in Swift 3 (beta 6)?

Tags: swift, set, nscountedset

Swift 3 introduces the `CountedSet` class (yes it's a class, not a struct) which should replace/bridge the old Objective-C `NSCountedSet` class.

However using the last beta of Swift 3 (beta 6) the `CountedSet` symbol is no longer recognised. What happened to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md), CountedSet has been considered and rejected or deferred.

> The following classes were considered and rejected or deferred for the
>   described reasons:
>
> OrderedSet, CountedSet: We will consider these types in a future proposal.